# How can I change the color of Material-UI Select Field HR element?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

[image: Very light grey line]

[image: Source HTML related to it]

Hi I have this Select Field component on my website I'm using from Material-UI. I am trying to override the style to change the hr that it generates which is light grey by default. It blends in too much with my background and it's hard to see. Which property from http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field can I use to achieve this? I've tried nearly all of them related to styling and I just can't figure out how to change this one specific part of the Select Field. I already changed the icon by adding the following code in React:

```
  iconStyle: {
    fill: '#000000'
  }

  <SelectField value={this.state.selectedvalues.priority}
  onChange={this.priorityHandleChange} floatingLabelText="Priority"
  iconStyle={this.props.iconStyle}>
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how I can override the hr element that it is creating.

Comment: Have you tried changing the **underlineStyle** property?

Answer (score 2):

This will change color of the text, the icon (dropdown indicator) and the underline to the same color for all of them:

```
<SelectField
  underlineStyle={{ borderColor: '#ff0000' }}
  iconStyle={{ fill: '#ff0000' }}
  labelStyle={{ color: '#ff0000' }}
>....</SelectField>
```

This is JSX so in plain js/css it's not camel case. Instead of `borderColor` it's `border-color`

Comment: can we apply multple styles to iconstyle?

Comment: yes, ofc, it's object which contains css properties in camel case, i.e. `iconStyle={{ fill: '#ff0000', paddingLeft: '15px', fontWeight: '800' }}`. But I don't know which ones are relevant for the icon. It's an **SVG**, if that helps you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the iconStyle, try this:

```
<SelectField value={this.state.selectedvalues.priority}
  onChange={this.priorityHandleChange} floatingLabelText="Priority"
  underlineStyle={{fill: '#000000'}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add this styling to your `<hr>` tag and try. To change it's color, so for that change `border-bottom color`.

```
<hr style="border-top: none rgb(224, 224, 224);border-right: none rgb(224, 224, 224);border-bottom: 1px solid #0086b3;border-left: none rgb(224, 224, 224);bottom: 8px;box-sizing: content-box;margin: 0px;position: absolute;width: 100%;">
```

```html
<hr style="border-top: none rgb(224, 224, 224);border-right: none rgb(224, 224, 224);border-bottom: 1px solid #0086b3;border-left: none rgb(224, 224, 224);bottom: 8px;box-sizing: content-box;margin: 0px;position: absolute;width: 100%;">
```

Comment: This will work. I can test it through Chrome only problem is with using React and Material-UI I can't directly edit any HTML in that way because it is generated. So I need a way of basically overriding the style created by the <SelectField/> component.

Comment: @Dan according to documentation provide on that website underlineStyle is one should work.

Comment: That's not how material-ui works. It has to be through parameters of the SelectField component.

Answer (score 0):

**Component approach**

Based on the [docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) it looks like you should be able to use the `underlineStyle` property.  Specify the css styles you're overriding.

```
<SelectField value={this.state.selectedvalues.priority}
  onChange={this.priorityHandleChange} floatingLabelText="Priority"
  underlineStyle={{'border-color': 'red'}}>
```

**Stylesheet approach**

After looking at the example documentation, it looks like there is typically a div wrapping the generated selects then a div wrapping the horizontal rules.  If you always want this and don't want to target it with javascript you could add a style to your css to override the styles.

The key to override is `!important`. But this will override everything.

```
div div > hr {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-style: none none solid;
  border-color: red !important;
  bottom: 8px;box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0px;position: absolute;width: 100%;
}
```

If you can add your own class to the selectfield then you can update the css to target that class.